# Trying to take user input and make a turtle dot

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

Trying to take user input in this case a numbers and make a turtle make a dot with the number that we got from the user input. It is for a school project that I am trying to do and I tried finding YouTube videos they really did not help.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.shape('turtle')
player.color('white')

def sad():
    player.dot(str(kj.get()))

top = tkinter.Tk()

top.geometry('600x600')

kj = Entry(top, bd =5)
kj.pack()

B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = sad)
B.pack()

wn.mainloop()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: There’s no reason to import a module, then import all the members of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Python turtle in conjunction with tkinter, you need to use the ***embedded*** turtle methods, not the ***standalone*** methods you used.  As turtle is built atop tkinter, you've effectively created two roots and will eventually run into trouble.  (E.g. images probably won't work for you.)  You're clearly confused by the combination as you call both `top.mainloop()` and `wn.mainloop()`!

Here's an example of how to *embed* turtle in tkinter for your program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle

def set_position():
    player.setposition(x_entry.get(), y_entry.get())
    player.dot(30, 'blue')
    player.home()

top = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(top, width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgcolor('black')

player = RawTurtle(screen)
player.shape('turtle')
player.color('red', 'white')
player.penup()

x_entry = tk.DoubleVar()
tk.Label(top, text="X: ").pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tk.Entry(top, textvariable=x_entry).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

y_entry = tk.DoubleVar()
tk.Label(top, text="Y: ").pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tk.Entry(top, textvariable=y_entry).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

tk.Button(top, text="Draw Dot!", command=set_position).pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

My recommendations are: first, try to work completely within *standalone* turtle if you can, and not introduce tkinter unless you really need to; second, don't trust any answer that makes this same mistake of trying to use *standalone* turtle classes *embedded* in a tkinter environment.

Answer (score 0):

with turtle you can tell it to go to a position using setPos commands. If you just convert the values from your user input into coordinates, tell you turtle to go there and then start drawing.

Here is a solution:

```
import turtle
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

#Setup
root=Tk()

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('black')

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.shape('turtle')
player.color('white')

def goToLocation(coords):
    #Get user input and split it into two different coordinants (coordsx and coordsy)

    coordsx, coordsy = coords.split(" ")

    #Set turtles position to the coords specified

    player.hideturtle()
    player.penup()
    player.setpos(int(coordsx),int(coordsy))

    #Draw the circle of size
    player.pensize(50)
    player.showturtle()
    player.pendown()
    player.forward(1)

    sleep(5)


#Button clicked handler
def retrieve_input():
    inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(inputValue)

    #Calls the previous function
    goToLocation(inputValue)


#Input box setup
textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()
buttonCommit=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Commit", 
                command=lambda: retrieve_input())
#command=lambda: retrieve_input() >>> just means do this when i press the button

buttonCommit.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Toby- It is poping up with a error in Lines 18,41,48

Comment: Have you copied the entire block of code across into your code file? This should replace the existing code you have - Make sure that you enter the coordinates as "xx yy" without the quotations.

Comment: Why `command=lambda: retrieve_input()` instead of simply `command=retrieve_input`?

Comment: cdlane sorry for the late reply - I was just basing the answer off the documentation I saw for tkinter as I don't have too much experience with it.