# Python Turtle constant text input box

Tags: python, input, turtle-graphics

Using turtle, i need to get constant text inputs. The ideal thing would be:
1. an input box fixed inside the main turtle.Screen()
2. the possibility of getting text inputs separated by an input event(ex. enter)

for the same needs and to the degree of my knowledge i found the turtle.textinput('title','prompt') not really satisfying. What kind of solution would you suggest?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to combine fixed input widgets with turtle graphics is to *embed* a turtle canvas in tkinter instead of running turtle *standalone* atop tkinter.

You can find an example in [Trying to take user input and make a turtle dot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58852362/5771269) - searching for `RawTurtle` will get you many examples.